# Performing Lookup based on Interval indexing, Pandas's Dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dictionary

I am trying to build a simple system whereby the system asks a User to input an age, input a sum assured (or amount he/she wants to receive), then based on those inputs, the system will tell the user the premium (or amount) he is to pay.

So far I have been able to let the code work (somewhat), however my problem is now iterating over all the columns.

This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
#data = pd.read_csv("/Users/Noel/Desktop/Transition.csv")


data = {'5000': ['18.67','19.79','22.16','26.38','29.17'],
        '7500': ['20.07','21.28','23.82','28.36','31.99'],
        '10000': ['21.46', '22.76', '25.48', '30.33', '34.81']}

transition_table = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['18-25','26-30','31-35','36-40','41-45'])

print('Hello, welcome to Axe!')
age = int(input('Please enter the age of the Policyholder: '))
sum_assured = int(input('Please enter the Sum assured of the Policyholder: '))

if age >= 18 and age <= 25 and sum_assured == 5000:
        row0 = transition_table.iloc[0, 0]
        print(row0)

elif age >= 26 and age <=30 and sum_assured == 5000:
        col0 = transition_table.iloc[1, 0]
        print(col0)

print('A Policyholder of age ' + age + ' with a sum assured of ' + sum_assured + ' will pay a premium of ' )
```

So when I input the age as 18, and the sum assured as 5000, I am supposed to receive an output of:
A Policyholder of age 18 with a sum assured of 5000 will pay a premium of 18.7

If i input the age as 27, and the sum assured as 10000, I want to receive an output of:
A Policyholder of age 27 with a sum assured of 10000 will pay a premium of 22.76

I guess I'm supposed to use a for loop to do the iteration, but I'm having difficulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using numpy `digitize` method solved the problem. This method map a value (or `array` of values) into bins,  for instance age 27 will map to the second interval (of index 1), the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'5000': ['18.67','19.79','22.16','26.38','29.17'],
        '7500': ['20.07','21.28','23.82','28.36','31.99'],
        '10000': ['21.46', '22.76', '25.48', '30.33', '34.81']}

index = np.array([25, 30, 35, 40, 45])
transition_table = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)

def get_value(age, sum_assured):
  row = np.digitize(age, transition_table.index, right=True)
  col = str(sum_assured)
  return transition_table.iloc[row, :][col]
```

Usage:

```
age = int(input("Enter age"))
sum_assured = input("Enter Sum Assured")
get_value(age, sum_assured)
```

Result:

```
>>Enter age 27
>>Enter Sum Assured 10000
>>'22.76'
```

Hope this helped, write a comment if anything unclear.

Comment: Wow @adnanmuttaleb you are a lifesaver! Thank you so much, it works perfectly!

Comment: the table is actually a small part of a bigger table in a csv file. I will attempt to use pandas to input it and see if I can get it to work. I'll let you know

Comment: @Noel You are welocom

Comment: hi again! so I've tried numerous time inputting the data and using the same code, and it's not working, I know it's a small thing I'm overlooking, but if you could take a look at the link (https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwD6v.jpg) which directs you to the Transition table. What do i need to add to the code to make it work?              
 import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("/Users/Noel/Desktop/Transition.csv")                                                 then your code was here

Comment: Hi @Noel  According to your question description, the code is working fine for me , I have tested multiple times. Now if there is another or new problem please open a new question and include all the necessary details, and write a comment about the new question's link, perhaps I can help you.

Comment: @Noel if this answer solves the question problem (no other details I do not know about) please mark this issue as closed.